# how to display array output in a vertical list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple page which displays 7 days on button click. I'd like the days to be displayed in a vertical list type of format, but the days are being displayed in a single line. When I try using the forEach function to display 'dayslist', it only shows one day name. How can it be displayed in a vertical list?? Thankyou.

[image]

```
HTML:

<div id="weekdivid">
  <h3>Days in a week</h3>
  <button onclick="showdays()">Show days</button>
  <p id="showdayspid"></p>
</div>

Javascript:

function showdays() {
  const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
  days.forEach(function (daylist) {
    document.getElementById("showdayspid").innerHTML = days + "<br>";
  });
}
```

Comment: You have JavaScript in your `HTML:` snippet.

Comment: Why aren't you using `daylist` in your `forEach` loop?

Comment: You're using the wrong variable, and you're not appending: `.innerHTML += daylist + "<br>"`

Comment: Shouldn't `document.getElementById("showdayspid").innerHTML = days + "<br>";` be `document.getElementById("showdayspid").innerHTML += daylist + "<br>";`, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use += instead of = in your foreach, something like:

```js
function showdays() {
  const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
  days.forEach(function (day) {
    document.getElementById("showdayspid").innerHTML += day + "<br>";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#join()` to add `br` tag.

```js
(function showdays() {
  const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
  document.getElementById("showdayspid").innerHTML = days.join('<br>');
})();
```

```html
<div id='showdayspid'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also refactor this slightly so that you're not using `getElementById` unnecessarily in the `forEach` to find the same element each time.

```
function showdays() {
    const dayNode = document.getElementById("showdayspid");
    const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
    let dayResult;
    days.forEach(function (day) {
      dayResult += day + "<br>";
    });
   dayNode.innerHTML = dayResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are displaying a list of related items, it would be advisable to use the proper HTML tag (either `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>`):

```js
const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];

function populateDaysList() {
  // select the list element
  const listElement = document.querySelector('#daysList');
  
  // if needed, you can style it to make it look like 'normal' text
  // or, even better, you style it in the CSS
  // listElement.style.listStyle = 'none';
  // listElement.style.padding = 0;
  
  days.forEach(item => {
    // create the list item...
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // ... add the text to it...
    li.innerText = item;
    // ... and append it to the list element
    listElement.append(li);
  })
}

populateDaysList()
```

```css
#daysList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<ul id='daysList'>

</ul>
```

Anyway, if for any reason you have to stick to the approach you used, you have to amend your code so that it *adds* new lines to the parent element innerHTML rather than entirely replacing it with a stringified version of the array followed by `<br>`:

```js
const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];

function showdays() {
  const containerElement = document.getElementById("showdayspid");
  days.forEach(day => containerElement.innerHTML += `${day}<br>`)
}

showdays();
```

```html
<div id=showdayspid>

</div>
```